# Gettext without a filesystem

Tags: c, localization, internationalization, embedded, gettext

For an embedded system with GUI, we are using our custom translation system. The strings are stored in the code ROM of a microcontroller.

Currently we have up to 10 languages and about 400 translated strings (varies depending on the product variant).

Our current system is rather cumbersome and I believe that gettext would be a better solution.

As far as I understand gettext, it requires the use of `bindtextdomain` to set the directory containing the compiled translations files (*.mo).

Is there a way to instead read the translation from memory? That is I would like to include the compiled *.mo files in the binary, and set up gettext to use these. Alternatively, the translation data would be stored in a data EEPROM without a filesystem.

Or can you recommend a different translation system for use in a microcontroller system (16 or 32 bit, 256 to 512 kbyte ROM) with a C interface?

Edit: I should add that being able to maintain translations apart from the microcontroller firmware would be a reason to switch to gettext. The appropriate translation data would be loaded by the user with a configuration software that we already supply with our systems.

Comment: Maybe gettext would be excessive in your case? Maybe you will do something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/bta-meteo-logger/source/browse/C/daemon/lang.h)?

Comment: You could either set up a RAM disk on top of the binary or fake file I/O.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do: I would include the binary ".mo" in constant variables in the code. You can write a simple converter from binary to a char array and have that ".mo" file compiled inside your program. You would have an array of ".mo" file data, each with a different language.

I would modify libintl sourcecode to access one of those arrays. Check the file loadmsgcat.c, the function `_nl_load_domain`. See there how it tries to use `mmap()` (so it's prepared to have everything in memory). Just add some code there to decide which element of your ".mo" array to use based on the language requested.

I haven't tried this, but this is what I would try given your situation. It doesn't look too hard.